# Getting graph-compatible Team and conversation IDs in a Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use the new message action feature in Teams in my bot application.  I can get the task module to invoke, but I want to have the bot read the contents of the full message thread (not just the first message as passed into the context).  When I examine the ChannelData though, I get this:

```
ChannelData {{
  "channel": {
    "id": "19:5e4ce488280b467198400257473cfd4e@thread.skype"
  },
  "team": {
    "id": "19:7a81d1b1c0b24ac192de1c3d5cfd5618@thread.skype"
  },
  "tenant": {
    "id": "8c6ae172-a3ea-4f50-994d-a0256822697f"
  },
  "source": {
    "name": "compose"
  }
}}
```

It looks like you should be able to get the messages in a channel using the [beta API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messagereplies?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp) like this:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var replies = await graphClient.Teams["303d2c1c-f1c5-40ce-b68e-544343d7f42b"].Channels["19:fec4b0f2825d4c8c82abc09027a64184@thread.skype"].Messages["1555375673184"].Replies
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

The challenge is, calling this using a TeamID, formatted as "19:7a81d1b1c0b24ac192de1c3d5cfd5618@thread.skype" doesn't work, and instead it needs the TeamID specified as a standard GUID (in this case, d12f244e-fd24-4430-a58a-1b2650ba8997).  Is there a way to convert between these two ID formats?  Is there something that details why they're different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can!

You have to use the [`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams` Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams) / [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet).

From the README, you can get the Team ID:

```cs
var teamInfo = await teamsContext.Operations.FetchTeamDetailsAsync(incomingTeamId);
```

That will be in `teamInfo.AadGroupId` and is formatted as the GUID.

Comment: Thanks, that got me the Team ID, which was one blocker, but the method call to get the message replies still throws an exception.  It looks like these are flagged as protected APIs though, which is why I'm getting the exception in the first place.  For anyone else looking to do the same thing, even if you have Group.ReadWrite.All, you still need extra permissions to get access to those APIs.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like in v4.3 beta of that package, the FetchTeamDetailsAsync method has been removed.  Needed to use FetchTeamDetailsWithHttpMessagesAsync instead

Comment: Interesting. Not sure what version I had, but `FetchTeamDetailsAsync` worked for me yesterday. Glad you got it working!